# Matriz de rastreabilidade de requisitos é a mesmo que rastreabilidade bidirecional entre casos de testes e requisitos?

Tags: modelagem, engenharia-de-software, testes

#### Contextualizando

Ao estudar para a certificação **CTFL** - Certified Tester Foundation Level me deparei com a seguinte estudo.

Segue Abaixo as Atividades básicas no Processo de execução dos testes

1. Planejar e controlar
2. **Analisar e modelar**
3. Implementar e executar
4. Avaliar Input/Output e Criar relatórios de execução
5. Criar Relatórios de conclusão

Com relação ao **item 2 (Analisar e modelar)** é explicado que entre suas atividades principais estão:

2.1 Preparar o ambiente de Teste e identificar as ferramentas necessárias

2.2 Criar uma **rastreabilidade bidirecional** entre requisitos e os casos de Teste

---

#### Minha dúvida

Olhando para o item 2.2 é correto afirmar que ele está falando sobre matriz de rastreabilidade?

Caso esteja correta essa associação, alguém poderia explicar e exemplificar com ilustrações essa matriz de rastreabilidade bidirecional entre requisitos e os casos de teste?

fonte: http://bstqb.org.br/node/197
Cap 1 Pg 16.